# How to implement this code: Hashmaps, <s:iterator>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2, hashmap

Looking for suggestions on the best way to implement the following:

I have a hashmap in the prepare of my action class. This hashmap has two values, FruitType and a Boolean. The available fruit types depends on the person using the screen. The boolean value also depends on the person using the screen.

In my JSP I have two forms:

The first form has a `<s:select>` list containing the available Fruit types.
The second form is only required if the boolean corresponding to the fruit type was true.
If the boolean is true, the second form is enabled and the submit button on the first form is disabled. 
If the boolean is false, the second form is disabled and the submit button on the first form is enabled.

I have no troubles with the enabling/disabling via javascript. My issue is where to store the booleans... I had a hidden input (isSecondFormReq) and a post on my select list (triggered when a value was selected) in the first form that worked out whether or not the fruits boolean was true or false, but i could not update the value of my hidden input field...

Does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Thanks heaps.

EDIT: I think maybe the best way may be to use `<s:iterator>` and have hidden fields where id=key and value=value... any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: read twice but still didn't understood completely, I agree with @AleksandrM - show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Finally read it thrice and I guess you yourself has proposed a solution, if the FruitType you can use the solution you mentioned i.e.

`create a map for fruittype,boolean and then iterate over it in the JSP, so that the 2nd form gets displayed based on the value of the selected fruittype and it's corresponding boolean`

I don't know how have you implemented the javascript, but I guess for the sake of completeness of this answer, I'll provide a small sample.

```
<select name="fruit" id="fruit">
<s:iterator value="mapFruitBoolean">
   <option value="fruit.key" data-boolean=<s:property value="value"/>>>Fruit.value</option>
<!-- Above fruit refers to the key of the map, and value is just a boolean
Map<Fruit,Boolean> -->
</s:iterator>
</select>
```

Javascript Code

```
$("#fruit").change(function(){
    var option = $(this).find('option:selected');
    if($(option).attr('data-boolean')){
       //Enable the submit button
    }else{
     //Disable the submit button
    }
});
```

Above code is untested, but I guess it should work fine, although I guess it clearly explains the concept.